# Find time of Windows unexpected shutdown

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I'm trying to find any clues towards time when Windows session was ended unexpectedly. Not only due to BSOD, but due to other reasons, like power outage, etc.

There is event 41 in event log, which allows me to determine that Windows session was ended unexpectedly, but event is recorded when Windows starts up, and does not contain any relevant information about shutdown time (so, I cannot tell, if it was 5 minutes since crash or 10 hours).

So far, the only clue I have is Reliablity registry values, such as LastAliveStamp, but apparently it doesn't work for my target Windows version, which is Windows 10.

I've also tried to check time of last event before event 12 (which is Windows boot event), but events are not periodic, so there are occurances, when there might be hour or so between two events, and this is way too inaccurate.

So, are there any more or less accurate and persistent ways to determine time when Windows session was ended unexpectedly?

Comment: [eventviewer - View Shutdown Event Tracker logs under Windows Server 2008 R2 - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/204417/view-shutdown-event-tracker-logs-under-windows-server-2008-r2)

Comment: Ticket mentions event 1076, which seems to be not applicable for Windows 10, and event 6008, which I've already investigated - it is even less accurate than "last event before 12" approach. For system crashed on 2:51 pm, last event before 12 was on 2:36 pm, yet event 6008 reported shutdown time on 2:18 pm. As you can see, first method was 15 minutes off, second - 33 minutes off.